# WPF layer multiplication

Tags: wpf, image-processing

There are two "layers" (Image control with PNG bitmap) inside Grid (or Canvas): one image directly positioned on top of other one. Is there a way to display combined image created by multiplying images colors (the Photoshop/GIMP layer effect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it dynamic you should look at WPF Effects. 
See [Greg Schechter's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/greg_schechter/archive/2008/09/16/introducing-multi-input-shader-effects.aspx was useful

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to chain together BitmapSources.  [Here's a blog post with details on how to do this.](http://blogs.msdn.com/dwayneneed/archive/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource.aspx)